# Can I traverse through an excel file using Indexes when working with Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Please excuse me if I am not clear. English is not my first language.

I'm trying to write a code where I can traverse through the first row of an excel file until I find the column labeled 'Comments'. I want to run some action on the text in that column and then save the result in a new column at the end of the file. Can I traverse the xlsx file in a manner similar to indexes? And if so, how can I jump straight to a cell using that cell's coordinates?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File myFile = new File("temp.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
    XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();


    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

        String comment = cell.toString();

        if (comment.equals("Comments"))
        {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }



    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question "Wanted to go to the second column's 3rd row I could use coordinates like (3, 2)?":

Yes this is possible using [CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html). Advantages over the methods in `Sheet` and `Row` are that `CellUtil` methods are able getting the cell if it exists already **or** creating the cell if it not already exists. So existing  cells will be respected instead simply new creating them and so overwriting them.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class CreateExcelCellsByIndex {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  //put content in R3C2:
  Cell cell = CellUtil.getCell(CellUtil.getRow(3-1, sheet), 2-1); //-1 because apache poi's row and cell indexes are 0 based
  cell.setCellValue("R3C2");

  //put content in 10 random cells:
  for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

   int r = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4, 11);
   int c = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 6);
   cell = CellUtil.getCell(CellUtil.getRow(r-1, sheet), c-1);
   String cellcontent = "";
   if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
    cellcontent = cell.getStringCellValue() + " ";
   }
   cell.setCellValue(cellcontent + i + ":R"+r+"C"+c);
  }

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelCellsByIndex.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLocation));

Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Map<Integer, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
int i = 0;
for (Row row : sheet) {
    data.put(i, new ArrayList<String>());
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
            case STRING: ... break;
            case NUMERIC: ... break;
            case BOOLEAN: ... break;
            case FORMULA: ... break;
            default: data.get(new Integer(i)).add(" ");
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 2D index, but a [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getColumnIndex--) knows which column it belongs to so something like this should work:

```
...
Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

String comment = cell.toString();

int sourceColumnIndex = -1;
if (comment.equals("Comments")) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    sourceColumnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
}
....
```

Similarly, define something like `int targetColumnIndex` to represent the column which will have the result from processing all the cells from the `sourceColumnIndex` column.

Comment: Thank you so much this is great. Yes I am sorry I'll change that to be more clear. What I meant was, that can I jump straight to a cell by using it's cell coordinates? Like if I wanted to go to the second column's 3rd row I could use coordinates like (3, 2)

Comment: No direct way with Apache POI that I know of.  But given `Row r = sheet.getRow(rowIndex)`, then you can `Cell c = r.createCell(columnIndex)`.